# Spinner not showing options from array in kotlin spiner

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, spinner

Spinner doesn't show options in kotlin fragment. There is `AlertDialog` that cotains this spinner but it's different xml file with HomeFragment
The code is below

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var view: View

    private lateinit var fabMain: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var spinner: Spinner


    private lateinit var categoriesList: ArrayList<String?>
    private lateinit var categoriesAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)


        fabMain = view.findViewById(R.id.main_fbtn)


        fabMain.setOnClickListener {


            insertData()

        }

        return view
    }

    private fun insertData() {
        var dialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        var inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
        var view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_insert_transaction, null)
        dialog.setView(view)
        var alertDialog: AlertDialog = dialog.create()

       ///Some code
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            alertDialog.dismiss()
        }
        alertDialog.show()
    }

    

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity)

        var dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_insert_transaction, null)
        spinner = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.category_et)
        categoriesList = arrayListOf("category", "category1")

        categoriesAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter<String>(dialogView.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                this.categoriesList
            )

        categoriesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        spinner.adapter = categoriesAdapter

    }

}
```

I tried to  place it in `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`. Also I tried to change first parameter in  `categoriesAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(dialogView.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, this.categoriesList )` to `dialogView.context`, `view.context` and `requireContext()`

Comment: Just for my understanding, do you want to display the spinner inside the dialog or do you expect it to be shown in the fragment?